# ExecuteTaskAction :app:processDebugManifest error Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I suddenly have an execution task action problem.

I tried the solutions at there and other pages but it didn't help cause they are old versions of Android Studio.

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asus.thesister"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

Error:

> :app:processDebugManifest error

Comment: Question is not clear. Share error logs and the links that you followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ExecuteTaskAction :app:processDebugManifest error Android Studio

The problem seems related with AndroidX library. It's because your are using Google play service with AndroidX with the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
```

Google play service starting from version 17, is using AndroidX. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019

You need to either downgrade your Google play service to version 16 (which is highly discouraged) or migrate your project to use AndroidX (See [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate))

Comment: Thank you so much i realize that i accidentally download adView instead of cardView and it caused a problem, now it is solved thank you :)